# Update SQL Server Management Studio editor window

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I was just wondering if someone can help with an annoyance I have with SQL Server Management Studio. When using the query editor it doesn't automatically update when new tables are created.

For example, suppose I create a table and then try to select from that table autocomplete will not find the table and the editor window will show the table as non-existing (i.e. the editor will try to "help" me by saying the table doesn't exist). I was wondering if there was a setting or tweak that can either refresh editors on change or on a time interval.

Any advice will be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried CTRL + SHIFT + R? It's the shortcut for Edit > Advanced > Refresh Intellisense Cache (or something close to it)

Comment: hehe that does it and is a good enough solution for me. if you want to post it as an answer I can tag it as a solution. Btw the shortcut is correct but for other readers it points in 2008 management studio to Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comment above - CTRL+SHIFT+R or Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache work